# Problem with constructing basis solutions to differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I was working on a physics problem and ran into the following 1st-order differential equation:
$$ x f'(x)+(1+i\lambda)f(x) = 0 \, ,$$
where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x): (-\infty, \infty) \to \mathbb{C}$.
The equation above can be solved to give
$$ f_{\lambda}(x) = x^{-1-i\lambda} \, .$$
I would like to construct a set of (orthonormal) basis functions $\{ f_{\lambda}\}$ labelled by the continuous parameter $\lambda$.

The inner product that I'm dealing with in this problem is defined as
$$ (f, g) \equiv \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, x \, f^*(x) g(x) \, .$$
Plugging in the solutions $f_{\lambda}$, we have
\begin{align}
(f_{\lambda}, f_{\lambda'}) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, \frac{1}{x} \, x^{i(\lambda-\lambda')} \\
&= \left[ 1 - e^{-\pi(\lambda-\lambda')} \right] \delta(\lambda-\lambda') \, ,
\end{align}
where the second term in the square brackets comes from the $x < 0$ contribution.

The term in the square brackets vanishes when $\lambda = \lambda'$, which implies that the set $\{ f_{\lambda}\}$ is not linearly independent since $(f_{\lambda}, f_{\lambda}) = 0$ (i.e. when considering $0 = \int d\lambda \, C_{\lambda} f_{\lambda}$, $C_{\lambda}$ need not be zero). Therefore I'm stuck.

However, after fiddling around a bit, and out of nowhere, I decided to consider instead
$$ f_{\lambda}(x) = (ix)^{-1-i\lambda} \, .$$
Surprisingly, now the functions are orthogonal:
\begin{align}
(f_{\lambda}, f_{\lambda'}) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, \frac{1}{x} \, (-ix)^{i \lambda} (ix)^{-i\lambda'} \\
&= (e^{\pi\lambda}-e^{-\pi \lambda}) \, \delta(\lambda-\lambda') \, .
\end{align}
The mathematical difference between this and the original case, I suppose, arises from the fact that
$$ Log(-i) = -i \frac{\pi}{2} \neq Log(i) + Log(-1) = i \frac{3\pi}{2} \, .$$

I apologize for such a long introduction, but **my main question is whether there is any formal way for me to obtain the latter case, i.e. the orthogonal set of solutions?**

Comment: You have a nasty singularity at zero. You should first test if it is possible at all to get solutions in an extended sense that are defined on all of $\Bbb R$, and why they should share the same integration constant. The natural domain of solutions are the intervals $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ separately.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks so much for the comment! Not sure if I fully understood your point. Are you saying that due to the singularity at zero, the best I could write as the solution is 
$$ f_{\lambda}(x > 0) = \mathcal{N}_{\lambda}^+ x^{-1-i\lambda} \, ,$$
and
$$f_{\lambda}(x < 0) = \mathcal{N}_{\lambda}^- |x|^{-1-i\lambda}$$

Comment: Yes. But with no connection across $x=0$, what is the idea behind considering global solutions?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Silly me. I actually didn't notice the singularity at first glance, and was just aiming to contruct a set of basis solutions with support on the entire real axis.

Comment: @LutzLehmann So with the well-behaved solution written above, we have
$$ (f_{\lambda}, f_{\lambda'}) = 2 \pi \left( |\mathcal{N}_{\lambda}^+|^2 - |\mathcal{N}_{\lambda}^-|^2 \right) \delta(\lambda - \lambda') 
$$
Thus if I'm not mistaken, making the functions orthonormal fixes 
$$ |\mathcal{N}_{\lambda}^+|^2 - |\mathcal{N}_{\lambda}^-|^2 = 1/2\pi \, ,$$
while the boundary condition $f_{\lambda}(x_0)$ at some $x_0$ fixes both $\mathcal{N}_{\lambda}^+$ and $\mathcal{N}_{\lambda}^-$?